# Is it possible to git clone from a remote repository but use objects from local repository to save bandwidth?

Tags: git

We have a repository that is almost a GB in size. Since it is an upgrade project (Python 2 to Python 3), most of the developers already have a copy in their local filesystem (which is probably out-of-date; and has their own remote names).

Is it possible to do a `git clone <remote-url>` such that it:

- copies the files from `.git` folder of the local filesystem
- sets the origin to the remote URL (and not the local filesystem)
- does a `git pull` to ensure everything is up-to-date

almost mimicking a fresh clone but avoiding bandwidth wastage?

I tried:

- `git clone file://home/project/local.git` but it doesn't set the proper remote; nor does it update.
- [--reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---reference-if-ableltrepositorygt) option: `git clone --reference /home/project <remote-url>`; but that also doesn't help despite its claim to save bandwidth.

I could write a bash function for this, but just wondering if this is supported by default?

Comment: Not `git clone` but `git remote set-url` + `git fetch` + `git pull`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. Run

```
git clone /home/project/local.git
```

to create a copy of what you already have locally. When you specify a plain path (not a `file:` URL), it uses hardlinks if possible to save space.

Then adjust the remote URL of `origin`:

```
git remote set-url origin <remote-url>
```

Now you can fetch the update:

```
git fetch --prune origin
```

(`--prune` removes any branches that you might have inherited from the local repository.)

Finally, do whatever you need to do to update the worktree. One possibility is:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: It seems like new versions of `git` has some capabilities to do this automatically; but I will go with this approach on my Centos 7.x machine.

Answer (score 2):

Your `--reference` was very close.  Assuming `file://home/project/local.git` means that you have an existing clone in `/home/project/local.git`, you want:

```
git clone --reference /home/project/local.git <remote-url>
```

to create the new clone, not:

```
git clone --reference /home/project <remote-url>
```

In general I'd recommend adding `--dissociate` as well if you can afford the extra disk space.  If you can't (afford the extra disk space), making a local clone and updating its `origin` remote, as in [j6t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887383/1256452), is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The `--reference` and `--dissociate` option seems to work in Git >= 2.3.0 as per the official [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---reference-if-ableltrepositorygt). But it seems to work only if the folder was updated recently (atleast on my system):

```sh
git clone --reference ~/cache/project --dissociate https://github.com/user/project.git
```